# Getting android spinner to display multiple items

Tags: android, android-widget

How do I get android widget spinner to display multiple items as shown below yet only allow to choose one?

[image]

Comment: You can use a listView instead of spinner.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is default behaviour of spinner.
here is how you can set multiple values in spinner.

Create a list of items which needs to be passed to spinner adapter
and add it as the last parameter in Adapter.

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, stringList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and can get selected item as follows

```
   spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the lines in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>
```

use the below line in xml

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />
```

Use the below line in your activity or fragment

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

  private Spinner spinner1;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
  }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

}
```

In my case, I have used the string resources, you can also pass a list